# Logical where grouping not respected in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure/data:

| id | date (DATE) | hour (INT) | tally (INT) | sum (INT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-15 | 7 | 12 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-05-15 | 7 | 1 | 4 |

With the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE
((`date` >= '2023-05-15') AND (`hour` >= '4')) AND ((`date` <= '2023-05-16') AND (`hour` <= '4')) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1000;
```

My expectation is that the data in the example is returned. I have two discrete where conditions (parenthesised). Instead when I run the query no data is returned.

Could anyone point out why the data is not being returned?

Comment: You can't satisfy one condition, and the opposite of it at the same time in the same record. Use the OR operator in place of the AND, between the two groups of conditions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd need is this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  (
    (`date` = '2023-05-15' AND `hour` >= '4')
    OR
    (`date` > '2023-05-15')
  )
  AND
  (
    (`date` = '2023-05-16' AND `hour` <= '4')
    OR
    (`date` < '2023-05-16')
  )
ORDER BY
  `id` DESC
LIMIT
  0,1000
```

Which is why you should never keep the date and time components separately.

It'as like storing `1.25` as...

| units | tenths | hundredths |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |

Comment: Thank you, and you're right re' schema. It's an inherited schema unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is the equivalent of this :

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE
`date` between '2023-05-15' and '2023-05-16'
AND 
`hour` >= 4 AND `hour` <= '4'
ORDER BY `id` 
DESC LIMIT 0,1000;
```

Or more precisely this :

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE
`date` between '2023-05-15' and '2023-05-16'
AND 
`hour`= '4'
ORDER BY `id` 
DESC LIMIT 0,1000;
```

Because you have no records with `hour = 4`, the result will be empty.